# Write jena TDB Query Results into Parquet

Tags: sparql, rdf, jena, tdb

I am not sure if it's possible to write the query results of Apache-Jena `tdbquery` directly into other file formats such as the columnar ones (e.g., parquet, or ORC).

Herein, how I use it with CSV, I want it to be one of the other file formats.

`./tdbquery --loc /location/.. --query  $filename  --results CSV> file.csv`

Notably, the idea is the file that I am writing has too many nulls, with CSV, it takes too much space more than the disk space I even have on the machine.

Comment: not possible with TDB, but Jena allows to register your own custom writer if you're a Java programmer - about which size are we talking for which query?

Comment: could you give me an example for that please?

Comment: Compress the CSV. If it has many repeats, the compression ratio will be very high.

Comment: Jena has output in Protobuf and Thrift : https://jena.apache.org/documentation/io/rdf-binary. They are not smaller but may help developing a solution.

Comment: Thanks Andy for your reply, but do you think that I can do the compression on the fly while querying the TDB and generating result set to the CSV file @AndyS

Comment: `./tdbquery --loc /location/.. --query  $filename  --results CSV | gzip > file.csv.gz`

Comment: Thanks, I think this is working :)